# Power BI show value of previous days

Tags: powerbi, datefilter

I have a report filtered on a **single specific day**. I am trying to have a bar chart that shows the 6 previous days until the day selected, something like:

[image: Bar chart of the 6 previous days]

A sample of data:

[image: X table data sample]

The single select filter on day:

[image: Single select filter]

I want to allow the user the perform a single select on a day, and then show the values for the 6 previous day from that day, and eventually add a "year to date" column at the end. I am currently trying to reproduce a method I found [here](http://sqljason.com/2018/03/display-last-n-months-selected-month-using-single-date-dimension-in-power-bi.html), but wonder if there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? It's hard to answer without knowing how your data is laid out.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've edited the question to add details about data. Thank you for trying to hepl.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak Can you post a screenshot of your source table structure with sample values. Post it as your source with making any transformations. You should get answer quickly, what you are asking seems simple.

Comment: @Sid29 I've added a sample data for table X, and I simplified my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating two new tables, one for your date slicer and one for your chart labels.

The first you can do easily with a new calculated table:

```
DateSlicer = VALUES(Table1[daytime])
```

For the `Labels` table, Enter Data like this:

```
Day  Index
----------
D-6  -6
D-5  -5
D-4  -4
D-3  -3
D-2  -2
D-1  -1
D     0
```

With these tables set up, let's write some measures.

```
ColumnDate = SELECTEDVALUE(DateSlicer[daytime]) + MAX(Labels[Index])
```

This measure is to calculate which day's values to use in a particular column, which we then use in the measures to sum the values we want.

```
ValueA = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[a]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[daytime] = [ColumnDate]))
ValueB = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[b]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[daytime] = [ColumnDate]))
```

The result should look something like this:

[image: Output Example]

Comment: That is a great answer and exactly what I needed, I understand better how to manage the problem. But with that method, how can I add a last bar which shows the YTD value as in my example ? Maybe with a CASE statement in ValueA and ValueB formulas ?

Comment: Yes. You'd add YTD to your `Labels` table and then have your `ValueA` and `ValueB` measures use an `IF` or `SWITCH` function that provides an alternate calculation for YTD.